# tcp listner With Threading performance

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcp

i'm building GPS application where GPS devices send location by tcp port
i'm building a service to read these messages and save it to database

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8889);
        TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
        int counter = 0;

        serverSocket.Start();
        //  Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Server Started");

        counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            counter += 1;
            clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
            //  Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "Client No:" + Convert.ToString(counter) + " started!");
            handleClinet client = new handleClinet();
            client.startClient(clientSocket, Convert.ToString(counter));
        }

        clientSocket.Close();
        serverSocket.Stop();
        //   Console.WriteLine(" >> " + "exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

//Class to handle each client request separatly
public class handleClinet
{

    static void WriteLog(string message, EventLogEntryType type)
    {

        using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
        {
            eventLog.Source = "Application";
            eventLog.WriteEntry(message, type, 101, 1);
        }
    }
    static int InsideDangerArea(double Lat, double Lng)
    {

        string point = "POINT(" + Lng + "  " + Lat + ")";

        string ConnStr = "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = GPS_Tracking;Integrated Security = True";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select id from T_Geofncies", conn))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string Query = "  DECLARE @g geometry; DECLARE @h geometry; SET @g = (select(points) from T_Geofncies where id=" + dr["id"].ToString() + " );";
                    Query += " SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('" + point + "', 4326); SELECT @g.STContains(@h);";
                    comm.CommandText = Query;
                    int Val = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
                    if (Val == 1)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                        return Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
                    }

                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    static int OutsideSafeArea(double Lat, double Lng)
    {

        string point = "POINT(" + Lng + "  " + Lat + ")";

        string ConnStr = "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = GPS_Tracking;Integrated Security = True";
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select id from T_SafeArea", conn))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(comm.ExecuteReader());

                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string Query = "  DECLARE @g geometry; DECLARE @h geometry; SET @g = (select(points) from T_SafeArea where id=" + dr["id"].ToString() + " );";
                    Query += " SET @h = geometry::STGeomFromText('" + point + "', 4326); SELECT @g.STContains(@h);";
                    comm.CommandText = Query;
                    int Val = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());
                    if (Val == 1)
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                        conn.Dispose();
                        return Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]);
                    }

                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    static SqlGeography GetGeographyFromText(String pText)
    {
        SqlString ss = new SqlString(pText);
        SqlChars sc = new SqlChars(ss);
        try
        {
            return SqlGeography.STPointFromText(sc, 4326);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    TcpClient clientSocket;
    string clNo;
    public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, string clineNo)
    {
        this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
        this.clNo = clineNo;
        Thread ctThread = new Thread(doChat);
        ctThread.Start();
    }
    private void doChat()
    {
        string ConnStr = "Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = GPS_Tracking;Integrated Security = True";

        int requestCount = 0;
        // byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
        string dataFromClient = null;
        Byte[] sendBytes = null;
        string serverResponse = null;
        string rCount = null;
        requestCount = 0;

        while ((true))
        {
            try
            {
                requestCount = requestCount + 1;
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                int i;
                int size = (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize;
                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[size];
                string data = "";
                string IMEI;
                while ((i = networkStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);

                        string[] tokens = data.Split(new[] { "GPRMC" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
                        var longest = Regex.Matches(data, @"\d+").Cast<Match>().OrderByDescending(m => m.Length).First();


                        IMEI = longest.ToString();
                        if (IMEI.Length > 15)
                            IMEI = IMEI.Substring(1);



                        foreach (string item in tokens)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                string[] Values = item.Split(',');                                   // Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);
                                string time = Values[1];
                                // Console.WriteLine("Time= " + time);
                                string lat;
                                string lng;
                                string speed;
                                string date;

                                lat = Values[3];
                                lng = Values[5];
                                speed = Values[7];
                                date = Values[9];

                                string NewDString = date.Substring(2, 2) + date.Substring(0, 2) + date.Substring(4, 2);

                                //  Console.WriteLine("IMEI= " + IMEI);

                                // Alternate choice: If the string has been input by an end user, you might  
                                // want to format it according to the current culture: 
                                // IFormatProvider culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
                                string myDate = (NewDString + time).Insert(2, "-").Insert(5, "-").Insert(8, " ").Insert(11, ":").Insert(14, ":");


                                double latDeg = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(lat).ToString().Substring(0, 2));
                                double latMin = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(lat).ToString().Substring(2));

                                double lngDeg = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(lng).ToString().Substring(0, 2));
                                double lngmin = Convert.ToDouble(Convert.ToDouble(lng).ToString().Substring(2));

                                double latmap = latDeg + (latMin / 60);
                                //  OldLat=
                                double lngmap = lngDeg + (lngmin / 60);
                                //if ((Math.Round(latmap, 3) != Math.Round(OldLat, 3) && Math.Round(lngmap, 3) != Math.Round(OldLng, 3)) || idleRecord > 30)
                                //{
                                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
                                {
                                    conn.Open();
                                    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                                    {
                                        // DbCommand also implements IDisposable

                                        // create command with placeholders
                                        cmd.CommandText =
                                           "INSERT INTO T_Tracking " +
                                           "([IMEI], [TrackTime],  [Longitude], [Lattitude],  [speed],[MapPoint],[SafeAreaID],[GeoFenceID]) " +
                                           "VALUES(@IMEI, @TrackTime,  @Longitude, @Lattitude,  @speed,@MapPoint,@SafeAreaID,@GeoFenceID)";


                                        SqlParameter p_IMEI = new SqlParameter("@IMEI", IMEI);
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_IMEI);

                                        SqlParameter p_TrackTime = new SqlParameter("@TrackTime", myDate);
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_TrackTime);

                                        SqlParameter p_Longitude = new SqlParameter("@Longitude", lngmap);
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_Longitude);

                                        SqlParameter p_Lattitude = new SqlParameter("@Lattitude", latmap);
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_Lattitude);

                                        SqlParameter p_Speed = new SqlParameter("@speed", speed);
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_Speed);
                                        SqlParameter p_Points = new SqlParameter("@MapPoint", System.Data.SqlDbType.Udt);
                                        p_Points.UdtTypeName = "geometry";
                                        p_Points.Value = GetGeographyFromText("Point(" + lngmap + "  " + latmap + ") ");
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(p_Points);
                                        SqlParameter P_Safe = new SqlParameter("@SafeAreaID", OutsideSafeArea(latmap, lngmap));
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(P_Safe);
                                        SqlParameter P_GeoFence = new SqlParameter("@GeoFenceID", InsideDangerArea(latmap, lngmap));
                                        cmd.Parameters.Add(P_GeoFence);
                                        // execute
                                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                    }
                                    //}
                                    //else
                                    //    idleRecord = idleRecord + 1;

                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception exp) { WriteLog(exp.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error); }
                        }


                    }
                    catch { }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Console.WriteLine(" >> " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

it is working fine but the problem is performance
it is test system with 5 devices
it consume 95% memory on server on 10 minutes 
what can be done to optimize that code

Thank You

Comment: One problem you will soon face is, half packets/double packets. Because, TCP is a stream, and your are assuming that you are reading one complete message per Receive call.

Comment: My problem now is not that i can ignore incomplete or corrupt my problem is the performance of send/Receive

Comment: Thats why it is a comment and not an answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that every time a new socket connection comes in you are creating a new thread that never ends even when the underlying connection is closed. The thread procedure is wrapped with a catch-all exception handler inside a `while (true)` loop, and so when the socket connection is closed and a SocketException thrown this is caught and ignored and the thread procedure loops again. This will also prevent garbage collection of the socket objects and is probably highly CPU intensive as well.  Also the cleanup code at the end of main will never be called because of the while(true) there, and indeed would only close the last client connection.

Your thread procedure should correctly handle exceptions and stop looping when the underlying socket connection is closed.

Comment: i added catch it get the error message cannot access a disposed object system.net.sockets.socket    then i added networkStream.close and clientsocket.close but still CPU 92% hang after 20Min did what i added is correct or there is some thing else need to be done should i use Asynchronous Server Socket if it work ?? Waiting for answer  thank you  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx